# Linear Algebra Done Right Exercise 3.F.26

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $\Gamma$ is a subspace of $V'$. Show that
>   $$\Gamma = \{v\in V: \phi(v) = 0\ \forall \phi\in\Gamma\}^0$$

It's straightforward to show that $\Gamma\subset \{v\in V: \phi(v) = 0\ \forall \phi\in\Gamma\}^0$, but I can't come up with the reverse direction.

Comment: My edit should clarify things. Γ is a subspace of $V'=L(V,F)$, the space of linear maps from V to some field.

Comment: The book uses V' to denote the dual space of V. If V is a vector space over a field F, V' consists of all linear functions from V to F. So, the meaning of f(v) for f in V' and v in V is regular function application. The application notation isn't given any notation for arbitrary vectors.

Comment: I've described the use of the apostrophe in the previous comment; V' contains all linear functions from V to its underlying field. The 0 superscript is used to refer to the annihilator of a subspace U of V. $U^0=\{ \phi\in V' s.t. \phi(u) = 0 \forall u\in U \}$

Comment: @shaihorowitz: please read the comment above yours.

Comment: The most straightforward approach, I think, is to consider the dimensions of the spaces involved. It will suffice to find that the set on the right has the same dimension as $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, we have that  the double annihilator of a subspace is again the subspace (in general, it is the weak$^*$-closure).

So, since 
$$
\Gamma^0=\{v\in V: \phi(v) = 0\ \forall \phi\in\Gamma\},$$
taking annihilators again we get
$$
\Gamma = \{v\in V: \phi(v) = 0\ \forall \phi\in\Gamma\}^0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_m$ be a basis of $\Gamma$.

Then by Exercise 3.F.30, $$\dim(\text{null } \phi_1 \cap \cdots \cap \text{null } \phi_m) = \dim V - m.$$

Let $U := \{v \in V | \phi(v) = 0 \text{ for every }\phi \in \Gamma\}$.

It is easy to check that $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

By 3.106 on p.106,

$$\dim U + \dim U^0 = \dim V.$$

It is easy to check that $U = \text{null } \phi_1 \cap \cdots \cap \text{null } \phi_m$.

So, $\dim U = \dim(\text{null } \phi_1 \cap \cdots \cap \text{null } \phi_m) = \dim V - m$.
So, $\dim U^0 = \dim V - \dim U = \dim V - (\dim V - m) = m = \dim \Gamma$.
So, $\Gamma \subset U^0$ and $\dim \Gamma = \dim U^0$.
So, $\Gamma = U^0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U = \{ v \in V : \varphi v = 0, \forall \varphi \in \Gamma \}$. $U$
contains 0 and is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, thus a
subspace of $V$.

By problem 25,
$$ U = \{ v \in V : \varphi v = 0, \forall \varphi \in U^0 \} $$
Suppose $V$ has a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ and the dual basis $\varphi_1,
\ldots, \varphi_n$. If $\Gamma$ and $U^0$ disagree on $\varphi_i$ as an item
of their basis, then the two definitions of $U$ will disagree on $v_i \in U$,
which is a contradiction.

Thus $\Gamma$ and $U^0$ have the same basis.